# tensorflow python code issue on print

Tags: numpy

```
 {} {} <-> {} {}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "train.py", line 266, in <module>
        initial_weights=initial_weights)
      File "train.py", line 239, in train
        do_batch()
      File "train.py", line 224, in do_batch
        do_report()
      File "train.py", line 205, in do_report
        print ("{} {} <-> {} {}").format(vec_to_plate(c), pc,
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

This is the particular print code. I tried to do even though the process starts, still this error is shown

```
print ("{} {} <-> {} {}".format(vec_to_plate(c), pc,
vec_to_plate(b), float(pb)))
num_p_correct = numpy.sum(r[2] == r[3])
```

Comment: The `print` in the error message is not the same as the one you show in the code snippet. Which one are you using?

Comment: This is the line it is reffered to line 205 and it also shows the braces.

Comment: But they are not the same if you look closely

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is you have put a bracket in the wrong place when you are printing and using `.format`.

```
print ("{} {} <-> {} {}").format(vec_to_plate(c), pc,vec_to_plate(b), float(pb))
#                       ^ This should not be there
```

The `print` function returns `None`. Having that bracket there means you are trying to use `.format` on the returned value of the print function. You need to remove the bracket in order to use `.format`, so your print would look like:

```
print ("{} {} <-> {} {}".format(vec_to_plate(c), pc, vec_to_plate(b), float(pb)))
```